# having 2 app or one app with multiple modules

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router, angular-module

I am using angular and i wanted to know which one is better. I have my template which i have split into header,footer,side menu and main content. I wanted to know whether to use one module per section and then have another module to enclose the smaller ones, or to have each module with different ng-app and then bootstrap. I want to know the difference in terms of performance and best practice.

For the time being i have implemented with UI-router as follows:-

The view

```
<div  ng-app="baseModule" ng-controller="baseController as base" >
  <div ui-view >

  </div>
</div>
```

The routing :-

```
 $stateProvider.state('root-profile', {
        abstract: true,
        views: {
            '@': {
                templateUrl: 'app/shared/base-profile/base-profile-view.html',
                controller: 'baseProfileController'
            },
            'header@root-profile': {
                templateUrl: 'app/shared/header-profile/header-profile-view.html',
                controller: 'headerProfileController'
            },
            'leftSideBar@root-profile': {
                templateUrl: 'app/shared/sidebar/left/left-side-bar-view.html',
                controller: 'leftSideBarController'
            },
            'rightSideBar@root-profile': {
                templateUrl: 'app/shared/sidebar/right/right-side-bar-view.html',
                controller: 'rightSideBarController'
            },
            'footer@root-profile': {
                templateUrl: 'app/shared/footer-profile/footer-profile-view.html',
                controller: 'footerProfileController'
            }

        } //END views
    }); //END state

    $stateProvider.state('profile', {
        url: '/profile',
        parent: 'root-profile',
        views: {
            'mainContent': {
                templateUrl: 'app/components/profile/profile-view.html',
                controller: 'profileController'
            }

        } //END views
    }); //END state
```

I have a base-profile-view.html which contains the various sections to be injected. Each one of them have a different module. Then I have enclosed each sections module in base-profile view as such

```
var baseProfileModule = angular.module("baseProfileModule", [
    'ui.router'
    , 'footerProfileModule'
    , 'headerProfileModule'
    , 'rightSideBarModule'
    , 'leftSideBarModule'
    , 'profileModule'
]);
```

and then i have another main module which contains the baseProfileModule as such:-

```
var baseModule = angular.module("baseModule", [
    'ui.router'
    ,'baseProfileModule'
    ,'baseSearchFrontModule'
]);
```

Now what i wanted to know is this a good way of doing things, or there are other better ways of doing this.

Comment: Can only have one `ng-app`. As for the modules, explain your reasoning behind making so many modules. Personally i only create modules for functionality I can port to another project. There is no real need to create a module for every part of a page

Comment: I will be using the modules in another "project" related to this one. They have the same header,footer and side menu. I wanted to reuse these in the other project. In fact the project that i have the snippets above is the profile part of the user, I have another "project" which will contain the same sections but a different mainContent.

Comment: create multiple module and inject in one main  module

Comment: Yes i'm doing that currently. Means its a good solution?